# ActiveExplorer/Inspector selecting more than one item

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to tell Outlook to select only one mail item, but it appears to be selecting multiple (The internal program I'm sending it to is referencing "These documents" rather than "this document"). Because of that, it's not letting me choose a file type and I believe it's because the program is interpreting the file as a container instead of a file. 
tl;dr: Can anyone see anything in my code that would be allowing Outlook to select more than one mail item?

```
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
        If objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then
            Set currentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Message Selected.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Case "Inspector"
        Set currentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.currentItem
    Case Else
        MsgBox ("Please select a mail item.")
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

Comment: How exactly are you "trying to tell Outlook to select only one mail item"? You are no selecting an item, just reading the existing selection.

Comment: Is the "existing selection" not the selected item? I suppose I figured that the (1) was an array specifying to pick "1" item, am I wrong in thinking that's an array?

Comment: Almost, it is a collection. Reading anything from that collection will not change the selection.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that helps me understand quite a bit. I'll see if I can pin the code down to one file rather than one grouping of files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to iterate over all items selected in the Explorer window:

```
 Set currentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)
```

For example:

```
 For i = 1 To oSel.Count         ' Loop through all the currently .selected items
    Set oItem = oSel.Item(i)    ' Get a selected item.
 Next i
```

Take a look at the [How To Get the Currently Selected Item in an Outlook Folder from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240935) article for the sample code.

Also I'd suggest breaking the chain of calls and declaring each property or method call on a separate line of code.

Comment: I was actually just looking at this article, thanks for confirming that it was the correct article to be looking at.